# Choose directory path using primefaces

Tags: primefaces, directory, upload

I am using p:fileUpload - https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml for uploading file. But I need to **upload a folder and get the folder path** instead of file path using **Choose** option from UI.

Folder path as - /home/Documents/data/sample_data. I only need to retrieve this path from Choose option.

Is there any way I can do that?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2705

Comment: Thankyou for your reply! Could you please mention the working model or code here?

Comment: I haven't gotten it working just wanted to show you three was an Open PrimeFaces ticket about this very subject.